# What is the relation between the half-time and the line-width of a radioactive nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering

Are they inversely proportional to each other?

This is the case for the atoms, I think.

The problem is that, for those isotopes like uranium 238, the half-time is as long as 4.4 billion years, and this would imply an extremely narrow line-width. But the interaction inside the nucleus is very strong.

Comment: Line-width of *what graph*?

Comment: I don't think either sentence is valid.  Line-broadening of photon emission from electrons is due to the existing allowable set of orbitals (e.g. in a semiconductor); in isolated atoms the photon energy is quite specific and unrelated to the particular pair of levels that the electron "fell" from/to.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Assuming he means the energy width of the line associated with a decay process, that ambiguous phasing is actually very common.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21282/  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/32840/

Answer (score 3):

The intrinsic width of a line due to a decay process is related to the *lifetime* $\tau$ (not the half-life) by the energy-time version of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle
$$ \sigma_E \, \tau = \frac{\hbar}{2} \,.$$

Recall that the standard deviation of an exponential decay is the lifetime.

Be careful that you do not confuse the experimental resolution with the intrinsic width (in other words, you can't use a NaI crystal for this measurement).

Comment: This means for uranium 238, whose half-time is as long as 4.4 billion years, the line-width is extremely narrow. Can one really measure the width?

Comment: Wouldn't think so. But it works for a range of short-lived decays.

Comment: Related: [What's the slowest nuclear decay rate that's been measurably linked with a narrow energy linewidth?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162493/whats-the-slowest-nuclear-decay-rate-thats-been-measurably-linked-with-a-narro)