# How was the half-life of Uranium 235 determined and by whom?

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, history, radioactivity, half-life

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranium-235) that the half-life of Uranium-$235$ is $7.038 \times 10^8$ ($\text{703 800 000}$) years.

This is very long. Therefore, on a human time scale, the decay is very small, posing difficulty for determining the half-life.

So Who and how was the half-life calculated?

Comment: Identical to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7584/how-do-we-know-that-some-radioactive-materials-have-a-half-life-of-millions-or-e?rq=1

Comment: There is some overlap, but not the same question, I would say.

Comment: As in "Who did It", that's fair enough, (if you mean" Who first measured it" but the very best of luck to you in your Googling, I looked and could not find out.  I would guess the technique dates to the time of the Curies, Becquerel and Rutherford.

Comment: Call the half life a billion years. That is about 3E16 seconds. One mole of atoms is 6E23. So, about 3,000,000 atoms would decay per second.

Comment: For the extreme, Bi-209 has a half-life of 2 x 10E19 years!

Answer (score 5):

The earliest reference I've been able to find on the half-life of <sup>235</sup>U is in [*The Uranium Half-Lives: A Critical Review*](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/13/691/13691196.pdf), by Norman Holden, which reviews various early studies of each of the common isotopes of uranium (<sup>232</sup>U, <sup>233</sup>U, <sup>234</sup>U, <sup>235</sup>U, <sup>236</sup>U, and <sup>238</sup>U). The earliest study he cites is Nier (1939) (*A. 0. Nier, The isotopic constitution of uranium and the half-lives of the uranium isotopes, Phys. Rev. 55 150 (1939)*)<sup>1</sup>.

Nier looked at ratio of <sup>206</sup>Pb to <sup>207</sup>Pb in 21 samples of radiogenic lead - that is, lead that has been formed by radioactive decay, in this case, from Uranium. <sup>206</sup>Pb is a decay product of <sup>238</sup>U, while <sup>207</sup>Pb is a decay product of <sup>235</sup>U. He then determined that the [*actinium series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain#Actinium_series) - the decay chain of <sup>235</sup>U to <sup>207</sup>Pb - is 4.6$\pm$0.1% as active as the [*uranium series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decay_chain#Uranium_series) - the decay chain of <sup>238</sup>U to <sup>206</sup>Pb. Then, using the ratio of <sup>238</sup>U to <sup>235</sup>U in natural samples, he was able to calculate the half-life of <sup>235</sup>U. It is not mentioned as to how he was able to calculate the half-life of <sup>238</sup>U.

Interestingly enough, Nier's value is closer to the accepted value than the half-lives found in many later studies using $\alpha$-counting, which looked at the number of $\alpha$ particles emitted during the decay of <sup>235</sup>U.

---

<sup>1 I was able to find Nier's abstract in [*Report of the Committee on the Measurement of Geologic Time*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CUMrAAAAYAAJ&dq=The+isotopic+constitution+of+uranium+and+the+half-lives+of+the+uranium+isotopes&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (pages 45-46).</sup>